Are there SMART problems with this used SSD?
I've just bought a used SanDisk 480GB SATA SSD and I'm wondering whether any of the numbers displayed in SMART are bad please?
In Active@ KillDisk Ultimate it shows "SMART warnings" on the disk (not shown on the screenshot below). Here is the SMART info:

Is this just saying there are warnings because it doesn't recognise the last attribute, 244? I see 0 is displayed in amber.
Obviously the Power Cycle Count is 10x higher than the Power-On Hours Count - which I guess isn't great? (4426 vs 432)
The Unexpected Power Loss is almost the same as the Power Cycle Count - which I'm guessing is also not good? (4237)
How do I interpret the numbers in:



Attribute #.
Name
Value




165
Average Erase Count
2382


166
Minimum W/E Cycle
11


168
SATA PHY Error Count
53


169
Total Bad Block
234


173
Wear Leveller Worst Case Erase Count
11


187
Reported Uncorrectable Errors
16


230
GMR Head Amplitude
1616


233
Media Wearout Indicator
5410


234
Unknown Attribute - is this GB written?
26805



Are any of these numbers bad?
Here is the report from CrystalDisk Info:

The firmware on the SSD is up-to-date according to SanDisk SSD Dashboard.
I ran both the short & extended SMART test in SanDisk SSD Dashboard, which passed.
Here is the SMART data from SanDisk SSD Dashboard:



ID
Name
Value
Threshold
Health




5
Re-assigned Sector Count
0
None
N/A


9
Power-On Hours Count
436
None
N/A


12
Drive Power Cycle Count
4426
None
N/A


165
SLC Block Erase Count
2382
None
N/A


166
Minimum P/E Cycles
11
None
N/A


167
Maximum Bad Blocks per die
0
None
N/A


168
Maximum P/E Cycles
53
None
N/A


169
Total Bad Blocks
234
None
N/A


170
Grown Bad Blocks
0
None
N/A


171
Program Fail Count
0
None
N/A


172
Erase Fail Count
0
None
N/A


173
Average P/E Cycles
11
None
N/A


174
Unexpected Power Loss Count
4237
None
N/A


184
End-to-End Error Detection/Correction Count (EEEDC)
0
None
N/A


187
UECC Count
16
None
N/A


188
Command Timeout Count
0
None
N/A


194
Temperature
105.8ºF
41ºC
None


199
SATA CRC Errors
0
None
N/A


230
Media Wearout Indicator
6.80%
None
N/A


232
Available Reserve Space
100%
4%
excellent


233
NAND GB Written
5410
None
N/A


241
Total GB Written
2088
None
N/A


242
Total GB Read
4252
None
N/A


244
Temperature Throttle Status
Off
None
N/A



I think they used the SSD for photography stuff before, but I'm not sure. I do know that they used it on a Mac previously with the HFS+ filesystem (it's still formatted as this at the moment).
It's an internal SSD. If it had have been an external SSD then I might understand the Unexpected Power Loss number, if they had just unplugged the USB cable without doing a Safely Remove Hardware & Eject Media first (or whatever the equivalent is on Mac).
I can always return this disk if it looks like it might at all be dodgy, but I could do with some help interpreting the numbers please - so I know what to tell the seller. Any help is much appreciated - thanks!

The only thing I see as curious is the 4400 power on count in 430 hours of use and the unexpected power loss, so it was turned on and off 10 times an hour. Could be something odd there, but could be something about the system it was in. They could have had it in an external enclosure which might explain it if the enclosure didn't provide enough power. The drive has 5.5 TBW (total nand writes) which isn't stunningly high, but seems high considering one 430 hours used. Sandisk do not list a TBW for the Plus drives, maybe as they are the budget line, so it's hard to know how heavily used it is.

How does a drive has 234 bad blocks with only 2088 LBA written?  Even if each LBA was 4k the total written to the drive is about 8mb.

@cybernard I've added the SMART data from SanDisk SSD Dashboard. It is reporting the 2088 as Total GB Written, rather than the Total LBAs Written reported by Active@.

@DannyBeckett For S.M.A.R.T. data, please don’t post cells, instead please pull the information directly via smartctl -a /dev/<disk>, copying/pasting the terminal output into a code box (smartmontools is available for all OSes). Instead of a code box that takes up a third of a page, the cells/columns take up three webpages, possibly a little more depending on screen size.

@JW0914 You can clearly see I've made an effort to put the text there rather than images where possible, please don't be so pedantic; the data is tabular and therefore a table is the best way to represent it

@DannyBeckett My comment wasn't criticism, it was merely an FYI, as I know effort was put into it. While GUI applications can be used to pull S.M.A.R.T info, the standard way is to use smartctl (it's also what GUI applicationss use on the backend), and it's more efficient to display the info within a code box because code boxes are locked to a maximum size, providing scrollbars for content (smartctl output is already formatted by default - see #6 as an example)
